# React Jest test Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

Not sure why I'm getting this error in my simple Main.test file.

[image]

### The constructor of Main.js

```
export class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            location: splitString(props.location.pathname, '/dashboard/')
        }

        if (R.isEmpty(props.view)) {
            isViewServices(this.state.location)
                ? this.props.gotoServicesView()
                : this.props.gotoUsersView()
        }
    }
```

### Main.test

```
import React from 'react'
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import { Main } from './Main'
import Sidebar from '../../components/Common/sidebar'

const main = enzyme.shallow(<Main />);

describe('<Main /> component', () => {

  it('should render', () => {
    const tree = toJson(main);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('contains the Sidebar', () => {
    expect(main.find(Sidebar).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Is there a way to mock up the 'pathname'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you might have a few errors one being that in your test your not passing in any props.

And another from you accessing `this.props` in your constructor.

See your `if` statement but I'll put the fix here to be explicit

```
if (R.isEmpty(props.view)) {
   isViewServices(this.state.location)
     ? props.gotoServicesView()
     : props.gotoUsersView()
}
```

---

In Main.test

```
const location = { pathname: '/dashboard/' };
const main = enzyme.shallow(<Main location={ location }/>);
```

Comment: Ah, k got it.. I need to create a fake object in my Main.test correct? Object that is called props, contains `location.pathname`?

Comment: @LeonGaban, yes any properties which that component may use.